# How click a div with selenium in python to download a file (error: rootNode.elementsFromPoint is not a function)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I tried to download the Youtube charts Weekly from https://charts.youtube.com/charts/TopSongs/ as csv. (the download button is in the upper right corner in a SVG icon)

I used this code and tried two ways to click it but both gave me this error `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: rootNode.elementsFromPoint is not a function (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.106)"`

And this is my code, I already make sure that I found the right HTML element with `download_button.get_attribute("outerHTML")`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://charts.youtube.com/charts/TopSongs/')

time.sleep(4)

#######first attempt######

download_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='download-container style-scope ytmc-charts']/paper-icon-button")

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(download_button)
action.click()
action.perform()

#######second attempt######
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

check_box_el = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='download-container style-scope ytmc-charts']/paper-icon-button")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(check_box_el).click().perform()

driver.quit()
```

*Any idea about it? Thanks :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:-

```
download_elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='download-button']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", download_elm)
```